# Elastic Dynamic field mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

```
 ES version 6.8.12
```

I want to map all types to a given field in an index, it should store all types of data , instead of bound to specific type.
im facing issue  when the string is stored in Long type field.

```
[WARN ] 2020-09-14 06:34:36.470 [[main]>worker0] elasticsearch - Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>"5f4632bab98bdd75a267546b", :_index=>"cdrindex", :_type=>"doc", :routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0x38a5506>], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"cdrindex", "_type"=>"doc", "_id"=>"5f4632bab98bdd75a267546b", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse field [caller_id_number] of type [long] in document with id '5f4632bab98bdd75a267546b'", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"For input string: \"Anonymous\""}}}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Then you need to pick the `text` or `keyword` data type.

In your mapping, you need to set the `caller_id_number` data type explicitly to one of the above instead of letting Elasticsearch decide for you.

For instance:

```
PUT your-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "caller_id_number": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you can leverage [dynamic mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) if you want to automatically set the mapping for some fields:

```
PUT your-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "sources": {
          "match": "caller_*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "specific_field": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the dynamic mapping above, all fields starting with `caller_` would get automatically mapped as `text` while `specific_field` would be mapped as `long`...

Comment: then i need to specify all possible types  right ? can you give me example if you have im confused


  "properties": {
      "caller_id_number": {
        "type": "text"
      },
  "properties": {
      "caller_id_number": {
        "type": "string"
      },....

Comment: No just text, as it will work for any type of values

Comment: it shows error, illegal_argument_exception 
can you please show me something more in detail 
  
"cdrindex" is my index name and em_id and caller_id_number are two fields 
thanks.

Comment: {
                "_index": "cdrindex",
                "_type": "doc",
                "_id": "5f3eeeb73861893e3b52cde7",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
      "caller_id_number": 2674607107,
                    "log_entry": "{\"_id\"=>BSON::ObjectId('5f3eeeb73861893e3b52cde7'), \"caller_id_number\"=>\"2674607107\" }",
                    "@version": "1"
                }
            }
this is my document the filed "caller_id_number" may contain any uncertain value which makes trouble to insert into index for "Logstash"

Comment: What do you when running `GET cdrindex`? Please update your question with the result you get

Comment: {
    "cdrindex": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "doc": {
                "properties": {
                
                    "caller_id_number": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                  

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

its long type and it has to be text as far i understand.

Comment: See, your index still has the type long and not text like I suggested in my answer. Until you changed that type, it's not gonna work

Comment: because mapping already exist i'm unable to it shows  "resource already exist" it has docs as well,

Comment: You need to delete and recreate your index, you cannot modify the mapping of an existing index

Comment: what if i want default all fields to be text and other specifics to be whatever type